# Zurb Ink Email Header on mobile devices

Tags: html-email, zurb-ink

I have a header in my email with a logo on the right and some links on the left (all on one line). Works fine, but when viewed on a mobile device, the links on the left overflow to two lines.

I'd ideally like to have the mobile version display the logo on the top line and the links below it like the following:

DESKTOP:

```
Logo       Link 1 Link 2 Link 3
```

MOBILE:

```
        Logo
Link 1 Link 2 Link 3
```

How would I achieve this?

My code:

```
<table class="row header">
        <tr>
          <td class="center" align="center">
            <center>
              <table class="container" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;border-bottom-color:#bdc3c7">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last">
                    <table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="four sub-columns full-size">

                          <img class="left" style="float:left;width:180px !important;" src="#" width="180px">

                        </td>
                        <td class="eight sub-columns last full-size" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;">
                             <a href="#">Link1</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#"><span style="color:black;font-weight:100">Link2</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#"><span style="color:black;font-weight:100">Link3</span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what certain classes do in your html as I'm used to working with Inky, the templating language of Foundation for Email 2 but the work-around should be sort of the same.

Because of the way css works (cascading style sheets) you'll need to override the inline styles and the wrapping with a few !important lines in a media query at the top of your mail in the style tag.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
 td .example-class { width: 100% !important };
}
```

Or if you're using Inky only use the attribute `large` on your `<columns>` tag. Consequently, the `small` attribute will copy the value of the `large` attribute.

Your links'll be pushed under your logo as its container is taking up the full width.

To display your logo in the center (if you are using Foundation for Email 2):

- .float-center class on the `<img>` element
- `align="center"` attribute on the `<img>` element
- Wrap the `<img>` with `<center>` tags (needed for Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2011)

Or when using Inky: A `center` tag around your `img` would be enough to do the job.

Source for aligning an `img`: https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/alignment.html